# How to have "My Cart" link outside of Top Links?

Tags: magento

I've only been working on Magento for a few days but already it is so confusing. I'm starting to get my head around it but one problem is doing my head in at the moment.

My client wants a shopping basket sort of function NEXT to the top links rather than a "My Cart" in the top links. Simply, all I want to do is move "My Cart" out of the top links and place it in the top right corner next to a hopping bag, but have no idea how to get this link in that position.

For a visual example, the clients shopping basket is going to look similar to the one one Next's website.

[image]

Thank you for any help you offer.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To call the cart URL from anywhere, you may utilize the Cart helper:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl(); ?>
```

(The helper itself is located under *app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Helper/Cart.php* - it has other useful functions, e.g. the items count in the current cart*)

You can utilize this to include a link in the top links, located in *app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/top.links.phtml*.

I am referring to the base package here, in your own template the path is (most likely) *app/design/frontend/[Your Package]/[Your template name]/template/page/html/top.links.phtml*

"[Your Package]" is "default" if you don't use an own package.

*which would be

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount(); ?>
```